# How do I add a variable to $node from a module?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I would like to perform a lookup on $node->uid from a module, fetch a field from the user profile and then attach that field to $node for use in template files.

I can do this within a theme preprocess method, but my understanding is that adding data (and performing queries) the "Drupal Way" means doing it in a module.

I guess I'm asking what hook I want to target. (Please note that this module did not implement the content type I want to alter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [hook_node_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7). With this hook you can add info to a node.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to target a context, like only do this for nodes being displayed in full view? Unless I'm reading things wrong, it would appear to be a little wasteful to attach the field every time a node is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

> A possible solution can be
>
> - add a hidden field to your content type
> - use [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) to do your changes before node save process,get the node author uid, then get your field from that user profile.
> - Attach the field value to your node field
> - That'all
>
> Note : do not do node_save() inside hook_node_presave(), it will make
>   it not breaking recursion call.

keeping field value as hidden will not show the field on node but this will be available in views etc. so it will easier to extend further.

Comment: This is an interesting proposal, but wouldn't one downside be that whenever a user changed the field (in this case, a Twitter handle), we'd have old data on all of the nodes that were created this way?

Comment: If it is dynamic as you said twitter handle , then you must be updating the field on user profile as well,I assume on cron run. If this is the scenario then you can update the field on node as well.

Answer (score 0):

> Even the field is subjected to change you can use one more hook,
>   something like below
>
> - After a user is updated , catch the update action using   [hook_user_update($edit,$account, $category)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7) you will get the
>     updated fields on user entity in the $edit array and an easy check can
>     be made to see if twitter handle is updated or not, if updated get all
>     nodes the edited user is author of with your content type check then
>     udpate the node fields as well
>
>   - To udpate node fields preferably use, field_attach_presave() and
>       field_attach_update(), something like below

```
// snippet as example.
      $node = node_load($node_id);
      $node->your_field_name[LANGUAGE][0]['value'] = UPDATED_VALUE;
      field_attach_presave('node', $node);
      field_attach_update('node', $node);
```

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, and while this would kill the extra DB call (or user_load) for viewing, I'd prefer to just insert the twitter handle into page variables, if possible.